# Laravel permissions can() function | Authorization

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, authorization, roles

I have `users`, `app_roles`, `app_permissions`, `app_permission_app_role`, `app_role_user`.

The tables are self explanatory, I am creating permissions, Then assigning that permissions to new role on role creation, And then i assigns roles to users.

i check permission of the authenticated user like :

```
@if(auth()->user()->can('some route name'))
    Html...
@endif
```

The above condition checks if the user have access to that content or not based of the assigned role as we know that the role have permissions, And the `can('some route name')` parameter is a route name. **Its working fine.**

> Where i am stuck !!!

The table `app_role_user` had `user_id`, `app_role_id`, Now i added another column `organization_id`... (*Consider Organizations as groups, Where a user can be a member of that groups, And the owner of the group assigns single role(Can't assign multiple role) to that user*). Because now the user can switch between organization and the user can have different roles in different organizations.

I have to clear path for the :

```
@if(auth()->user()->can('some route name'))
    Html...
@endif
```

> **Note :** : `Auth::user()->current_org->id` show the id of the organization in which the user is in right now

As well as currently i am saving `role_id`, `user_id`, `organization_id` **in** `app_role_user` **table**.

Here is my `AuthServiceProvider` class,

**I am Dynamically registering permissions with Laravel's Gate :**

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    $this->registerAllPermissions($gate);
}

protected function getPermissions() {
    return $this->app->make('App\Repositories\PermissionRepository')->withRoles();

}

private function registerAllPermissions($gate) {

    if (Schema::hasTable('app_permissions') and Schema::hasTable('users') and Schema::hasTable('app_roles')) {
        cache()->forget('app_permissions_with_roles');
        foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
            $gate->define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) {
                return $user->hasPermission($permission);
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Here is `PermissionRepository` class :

class PermissionRepository
{
    protected $model;

```
public function __construct(AppPermission $model)
{
    $this->model = $model;
}

public function all(){
    return $this->model->all();
}

public function withRoles(){

    $model = $this->model;
    $permissions = cache()->remember('app_permissions_with_roles', 1*60*24, function() use($model) {
        return $model->with('roles')->get();
    });

    return $permissions;
}
```

}

And here is `HasRoles` **trait** having `hasPermission(AppPermission $permission)` because **AuthServiceProvider** class needs it in `registerAllPermissions`.

```
trait HasRoles {
    public function assignRole($role)
    {
        return $this->roles()->save(
            AppRole::whereName($role)->firstOrFail()
        );
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if (is_string($role)) {
            return $this->roles->contains('name', $role);
        }
        return !! $role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
    }

    public function hasPermission(AppPermission $permission)
    {
        return $this->hasRole($permission->roles);
    }
}
```

---

**What should i do, I have tried many conditions but nothing worked at all.
Looking forward to hear from you guys.**

*Thanks for the read, Need serious attention please.*

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

User Model

```
//add organization_id as pivot field

public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(AppRole::class)->withPivot('organization_id');
}

//define a function

public function orgRoles($orgId){
    return $this->roles()->wherePivot('organization_id', $orgId)->get();
}
```

Now in trait modify `hasRole` function

```
public function hasRole($role)
{
    $orgId = Auth::user()->current_org->id;

    if (is_string($role)) {
        return $this->orgRoles($orgId)->contains('name', $role);
    }
    return !! $role->intersect($this->orgRoles($orgId))->count();
}
```